# How to solve $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)^\frac{2x}{x+1}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I got stuck with the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)^\frac{2x}{x+1}$$

I know it has something to do with $e$ but I can't find out where to start.

Answer (score 1):

$x > 1 \implies 1<\frac{2x}{x+1} < 2$ and $\frac{1}{x^4} <\left(\frac 1{x^2}\right)^{\frac{2x}{x+1}} < \frac{1}{x^2}$

By the squeeze theorem, your limit evaluates to $0.$

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)^{2x/(x+1)}=-\frac{4x\ln x}{x+1}\sim -4\ln x\to-\infty$$
as $x\to\infty$. So your original limit is zero.

Comment: Did you mean $\sim-\ln x$?  (Argument still works)

Answer (score 0):

Because $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x}{x + 1} = 2$,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)^\frac{2x}{x+1} = 0^{2} = 0.$$